# Burn a CD on Mac on OSX

Tags: mac, system-installation

I followed [the instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-cd-on-mac-osx) and burnt a CD but when I booted with the the CD while holding C at startup on my mac nothing happens!

When I want to see the content, it says "The Disk you inserted was not readable by this computer"

What do I do?

OSX : Mountain lion

Answer (score 1):

From my experience burning disks via Disk Utility, sometimes it can simply mess up on the burning process. You should figure out firstly whether it's a problem with Disk Utility or just the disk. Your best bet is to try burning a second disk and see what happens when you boot.

Also, instead of booting from the CD via the C button, try holding down the option key instead to see a menu of bootable devices to select the disk from there.

Comment: Just a note for future people, I have a mac to and I use refind <http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html>. It works great and it is easy to install (unless you are using windows) on both linux and mac. (note that if you have a normal macintosh and you installed Ubuntu it is better to install rEFInd on mac and choose mac as your startup disk even if you use Ubuntu primarily as it will work best in the aforementioned way)

Comment: When trying to install from a dvd, restart the mac and hold the C key down. This will force a boot from disk. See comments here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20live%20CD ...

Answer (score 0):

Jdonner is right, I have had the same problem and normally its just a bad disk.  To minimize the chance of errors you can also burn your disk at a slower speed. On my Mac, I can do it at 24x or 8x.  When you restart hold down option and a set of bootable disks will come up, on mine, I get Mac OS X, Windows and the Ubuntu live disk when its in.

Answer (score 0):

A few observations

- make sure you verify the download with md5/sha1 so that you are not burning a bad download.
- if you are downloading 64amd isos, make sure you are downloading the +mac variant.  look for the description to say "adjusted to work properly on mac systems"

http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/